# Windows SendInput makes mouse cursor flicker and disappear

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, touch, sendinput

I'm writing a Windows Desktop program in C++ that consumes all touch screen input, replacing it with mouse input created via SendInput.  So far I just want any movement made with a finger on the touch screen to be sent as a mouse delta.  I should, for example, be able to use the physical mouse to place the cursor near the top of the screen, then drag my finger in a horizontal line along the bottom of the screen and see the cursor replicate that movement above.

This works except for three issues;

- Whilst I move my finger the cursor rapidly flickers between a normal mouse icon and one with a progress wheel.
- When I remove my finger the cursor jumps to my finger's last position, though if I touch the screen again it jumps back.
- If I hold my finger still on the screen the cursor completely disappears (it could be positioned under my finger but I obviously can't see there)

A little more detail about what I am doing;

I use CreateWindowEx to create an invisible message-only window.

I then use RegisterPointerInputTarget to insure all touch input is sent to my window.

In my WndProc function I return 0 without calling DefWindowProc, for all WM_POINTERENTER, WM_POINTERLEAVE, WM_POINTERUP, WM_POINTERDOWN, WM_POINTERUPDATE, WM_POINTERCAPTURECHANGED and WM_TOUCH messages.

I use WM_POINTERDOWN to detect new touches, WM_POINTERUPDATE to send appropriate mouse updates with SENDINPUT and WM_POINTERUP/WM_POINTERCAPTURECHANGED to stop tracking the touch.

*******EDIT*******

I now have a fix for the cursor disappearing when the user removes their finger from the screen; send two mouse movements from the WM_POINTERUP message.  I don't actually want the cursor to move at all so I send one movement of (1, 0) and then one of (-1, 0). This feels like a hack, I am sure it is, so if anyone has a better suggestion please let me know.

To fix the mouse disappearing when the finger is held still on the screen I had to  do the same thing in the WM_POINTERUPDATE message; split each movement I would send from there into two messages.  I also had to make sure I was sending a movement for each WM_POINTERUPDATE received (I had been skipping empty ones).

This only leaves the mouse flickering problem.  This can be reproduced much more simply.  Just use visual studio to create a new windows desktop application and add this code to the WndProc function;

```
    case WM_POINTERUPDATE:
    {
        INPUT Inputs[1] = { 0 };
        Inputs[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        Inputs[0].mi.dx = 1;
        Inputs[0].mi.dy = 0;
        Inputs[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
        SendInput(1, Inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
    }
```

Run the program, touch the screen inside the application window and the flickering occurs, This only happens if the SendInput calls are made from WM_POINTERUDPATE so I suspect the issue is to do with Windows wanting to hide the cursor as this is what normally happens when the user touches the screen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When a window loses capture of a pointer and it receives the `WM_POINTERCAPTURECHANGED` notification, it typically will not receive any further notifications. For this reason, it is important that you *NOT* make any assumptions based on evenly paired `WM_POINTERDOWN`/ `WM_POINTERUP` or `WM_POINTERENTER`/ `WM_POINTERLEAVE` notifications.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I have updated my code so that it stops tracking a touch when either WM_POINTERUP or WM_POINTERCAPTURECHANGED is received.  Oddly I never seem to recieve any WM_POINTERCAPTURECHANGED messages.  Presumably this is because, as an invisible message-only window, my program never captures the pointer.  This might explain why the cursor jumps to my finger's position when I remove my finger; if a WM_POINTERCAPTURECHANGED message is being fired that my app is not receiving.  I will look into this and will update my question to reflect this change.

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? And what's the `delta`, Note that if `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` is not set, The dx and dy parameters contain relative data: the change in position since the last reported position.

Comment: Sorry, I've not had time to produce a minimal reproducible example.  I'll try to do that soon, however for now I'll add the whole of my WndProc function to the question.

Comment: Note that in order to make this runable I have to jump through various security hoops. In Visual Studio's project settings for the Linker's Manifest File options I've set UAC Execution Level to highestAvailible and UAC Bypass UI Protection to true.  That allows me to make the call I mentioned to RegisterPointerInputTarget, but after the exe is built I still need to sign it with a trusted root certificate and copy it to the system32 folder before running it.

Comment: I have now updated the question with a simpler example that should be runable.

Comment: Did it hit the `WM_POINTERLEAVE`, and what's the cursor position when in `WM_POINTERLEAVE`?

Comment: Yup, it does hit WM_POINTERLEAVE.  I modified the simple version above to print out the mouse position during WM_POINTERLEAVE and WM_POINTERUPDATE messages.  The output looks like this when I hold my finger in one position on the screen; one long series of repeated "WM_POINTERUPDATE 364,563" messages followed by one "WM_POINTERLEAVE 364,563" when I remove my finger.  Once again the behaviour is the same.  So long as my finger is on the screen the cursor moves slowly to the right, flickering as it goes between normal and progress icons, then jumps to my finger when I remove it.

Comment: So it seems that stopping the cursor jumping to my finger when I remove it is as simple as sending one more mouse move message with SendInput from the WM_POINTERLEAVE message.  That just leaves me with the flickering.

Comment: I have narrowed down the mouse flickering to a much simpler repro.  I will update the question with this.

Comment: I thought the registry value; HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableCursorSurpression  would be an easy way to fix this but it doesn't seem to change touch input behaviour at all. I will make a separate question for this.