# Windows registry EnableCursorSurpression doesn't work for touch input

Tags: c++, windows, cursor, registry, touch

***EDIT*** - Updated with a better reproduction case.

I want to stop my cursor disappearing during touch input. I have set the registry value;

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableCursorSurpression

to 0 but the cursor is still being surpressed during touch input.

I have already asked a more general question about a C++ program I am trying to write to consume all touch screen input.  I thought this registry value would solve the problem so I wanted to ask a more specific question.  However my original posting is here;

[Windows SendInput makes mouse cursor flicker and disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56418729/windows-sendinput-makes-mouse-cursor-flicker-and-disappear)

Calling GetCursorInfo confirms that this is happening because the cursor is suppressed but setting the registry value to 0 makes no difference.  It doesn't even stop the cursor disappearing during normal touch input when my program isn't running.

This can be reproduced by simply changing the registry value and seeing if the cursor remains visible after touch input. To see the flickering I described just use visual studio to create a new windows desktop application and add this code to the WndProc function;

```
 case WM_POINTERUPDATE:
    {
        INPUT Inputs[1] = { 0 };
        Inputs[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        Inputs[0].mi.dx = 1;
        Inputs[0].mi.dy = 0;
        Inputs[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
        SendInput(1, Inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
        break;
    }
```

Runt the program, touch the screen inside the window and watch the cursor move to the right, flickering as it does.  The flickering isn't so bad when the cursor is over the program's window but it get's worse when it exits it especially if it then passes over another window with a custom cursor like, for example, an mspaint window.

Adding this code;

```
    CURSORINFO cursorInfo;
    cursorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(CURSORINFO);
    GetCursorInfo(&cursorInfo);
```

Allowed me to check the state and see the cursor is suppressed, regardless of that registry value.